# OpenCL kernel runs correctly on Intel GPU but failed with error -9999 on NVidia GPU

Tags: opencl, nvidia, gpgpu

I'm working on development of a library for calculation of various metrics of video streams.
It was implemented for CPU and GPU and validated successfully on CPU and Intel Xe GPU
but recently I found an issue with NVidia GPU.
In a few words: there are two kernels, 1st kernel does processing of some input and write intermediate results
to global SVM buffer, 2nd kernel uses these data from global buffer to calculate results.
The global buffer was created with read/write access (CL_MEM_READ_WRITE) without any error and filled from host using call to clEnqueueFillBuffer().
It works correctly on Intel Xe GPU but on NVidia card (Geforce 1030) I got error -9999 from clWaitForEvents() when
waiting for completion of 1st kernel.
If I commented writes to the global buffer then no any error reported.

I checked the size of the buffer (it's correct, 13MB approximately).
I checked initial buffer's content on kernel side using printf and it is valid.
I checked the required alignment of access (short, 2) and it is correct too.

What could be the reason for the above error?

Comment: In my experience -9999 for Nvidia generally means an address bounds violation on the device side. Some devices don't detect out of bounds accesses in certain situations. Thus Intel might work even though you have an out of bounds access. You might need a Minimal Reproducible Example to help debug this.

Comment: NVidia appear to support OpenCL begrudgingly, preferring CUDA instead. I think NVidia GPUs only support OpenCL up to version 1.2 (?) so you might have some version issues. Just a thought. I'd check what version your program is set to use.

Comment: @Tim Thank you! I agree with you. Some time ago I fixed an error in another kernel which failed with -9999 error code and it was really caused by out of the bounds global buffer access. But now I checked the buffer size and access address twice.

Comment: I will try to provide MRE next week.

Comment: @Simon Goater. Thank you! My kernels were compiled for OpenCL 2.0 API. clinfo reported that NVidia OpenCL 3.0 CUDA API is supported by the driver.

Comment: @Alexander Strakhov OpenCL 3.0 = rebranded 1.2, and does not include the extra 2.0/2.1/2.2 features. If you use these 2.x features, the code will not compile for Nvidia cards.

Answer (score 0):

Intel supports the more feature-rich OpenCL C 2.x, Nvidia only OpenCL C 1.2. "OpenCL 3.0" is the platform version, where 3.0 = rebranded 1.2, and the language standard is still 1.2.

If you are using any OpenCL C 2.x-specific features in the kernel, it will work on an Intel GPU, but not on Nvidia. The solution is to try to replace these 2.x features with standard OpenCL 1.2.